# Construct JSON Object based on Query Result List

Tags: java, json, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

Trying to figure out a solution for a problem I am facing, but cannot find any material online so far to help me.

Essentially what I have is a method in a rest controller that passes a query string to my Hibernate DAO and gets in return data requested.

e.g.

```
@RequestMapping("/submitQuery")
    public Object submitQuery() {
// example of a query string, note this is dynamic and thus never hardcoded
        String query = "SELECT C.amount, C.transactionDate, R.amount, R.transactionDate FROM CAR C, RFT R";

        return  DAO.submitQuery(query);
    }
```

DAO:

```
public List<T> submitQuery(String query) {
        Query q = getSession().createQuery(query);
        return q.list();
    }
```

This query string will be dynamic so the option of creating a entity and attaching it against query is not an option.

The above method will return data in following format:

```
[
    [
        -4890.38,
        1451826000000,
        25.04,
        1421499600000
    ],
    [
        -660,
        1413205200000,
        25.04,
        1421499600000
    ],
    [
        -10768.53,
        1423054800000,
        25.04,
        1421499600000
    ]
]
```

So no headers and on top of that dates have been converted into digits.
What i want to achieve is have the method return the results in following format:

```
[
    [
        "amountc" : -4890.38,
        "datec" : "01-03-2014",
        "amountr" : 25.04,
        "dater" : "01-03-2014"
    ],
    [
        "amountc" : -660,
        "datec" : "03-02-2014",
        "amountr" : 25.04,
        "dater" : "03-02-2014"
    ],
    [
        "amountc" : -10768.53,
        "datec" : "01-02-2014",
        "amountr" : 25.04,
        "dater" : "01-02-2014"
    ]
]
```

Any advice/assistance would be appreciated.

**NOTE: Cannot use DTOs or Entities as the Query String is dynamic and changes. Query string i have there is just as example.**

Comment: Create a Data Transfer Object with the fields `ammountc,datec,amountr,dater` and instead of returning `DAO.submitQuery(query)` build a DTO list from this list and return it.

Comment: Query string changes therefore DTO would need to change. Cannot use objects.

Comment: Convert the result into Map

Comment: Can you provide example of what you mean @ShijuKBabu

Answer (score 3):

I think [Sunil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4715181/sunil) already answered. Check the edited section on how to convert to map. Or try the following

```
public List<Map<String,Object>> submitQuery(String query) {
        Query q = getSession().createQuery(query);
        return q.setResultTransformer(Transformers.ALIAS_TO_ENTITY_MAP).list();
    }
```

Comment: Voila! Magic it is.. ;) But column's sequence got changed in JSON format somehow..

Comment: Thank you..  List<Map<String,Object>> worked perfectly for me.

Answer (score 2):

create a bean class let `ABC.java` which contains the setter and getter methods and override `toString` into DTO class  like this.

```
  public class ABC implements Serializable{

    private double amountc;
    private String datec;
    private double amountr;
    private String  dater;

    ... setter and getters

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return "[\"amountc:\""+amountc+",\"datec:\""+datec+",\"amountr:\""+amountr+",\"dater:\""+dater+"]";
    }
}
```

and make few change into DAO implementations class

```
public List<ABC> submitQuery(String query) {
    Query q = getSession().createQuery(query).setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(ABC.class));
    List<ABC> resultList=q.list();
    System.out.println(resultList); //desire output 
    return resultList;
}
```

please make sure that data types should be same into entity and DTO class `ABC`

**EDITED**

in case of you don't want any bean or DTO then you can use `Criteria.ALIAS_TO_ENTITY_MAP` which transformer the result query into a map object with key-value pair.keys name are same as alias name into sql query.if you are not using alias into sql query then key's  are like 0,1,2,3,.... and so on.

```
public List<ABC> submitQuery(String query) {
        Query q = getSession().createQuery(query).setResultTransformer(Criteria.ALIAS_TO_ENTITY_MAP);
        List<ABC> resultList=q.list();
        System.out.println(resultList); //desire output 
        return resultList;
    }
```

Comment: Did you read the part where it says "cannot use entity or DTO"? What happens when the query changes to "select r.id from car r"?

Comment: if you don't want DTO or entity then you can use 'Criteria.ALIAS_TO_ENTITY_MAP' transfer the result into hash map with key and values pair.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell without knowing how the `T` looks like... but I believe `T`'s `toString` method is your friend.

Comment: T is irrelevant as it will return a Object containing results. But again i cannot use predefined entities as the query string changes.

Comment: T is not irrelevant as long as it appears in your DAO submitQuery method signature

Comment: you don't have to define T, so it will return a object making it irrelevant as to what it is.

Comment: That is not what I was saying. You can enforce certain format of toString though

Comment: Right, but that is assuming that there is a specific object/entity to convert into a string. I am not using object/entity as the query is dynamic and can change on a whim.

Comment: I am not sure how query string is dynamic. Right now in your example it is hardcoded text. Without assuming some attributes/interfaces that are available on the objects you are operating with achieving what you want to achieve would be difficult. You must at least have the fields you are interested in to begin with, right? So, why not define som kind of interface? It is a good practice.

Comment: Ignore the hardcoded string. The whole point is to get a random query string and then get a response object in form of results

Comment: not sure I get what you are looking for mbut good luck with that anyway )))

Answer (score -1):

you can create a object model

for example

```
class TransObj  {

public double amountc;
public String datec;
public double amountr;
public String  dater;
public double getAmountc() {
    return amountc;
}
public void setAmountc(double amountc) {
    this.amountc = amountc;
}
public String getDatec() {
    return datec;
}
public void setDatec(String datec) {
    this.datec = datec;
}
public double getAmountr() {
    return amountr;
}
public void setAmountr(double amountr) {
    this.amountr = amountr;
}
public String getDater() {
    return dater;
}
public void setDater(String dater) {
    this.dater = dater;
}
}
```

then modify you code to this

```
@RequestMapping("/submitQuery")
public List<TransObj> submitQuery() {
    String query = "SELECT C.amount as amountc, C.transactionDate as datec, R.amount as amountr, R.transactionDate as dater FROM CAR C, RFT R";

    return  DAO.submitQuery(query);
}


public List<TransObj> submitQuery(String query) {
        Query q = getSession().createQuery(query);
        return q.list();
    }
```

Comment: With objects its easy, I cannot use objects as the query string is dynamic so the minute it changes your object becomes obsolete and throws a error.

Answer (score -1):

Use the select new map syntax in HQL to fetch the results of each row in a Map.

Basically if you structure your HQL query like this:

```
"SELECT new HashMap(user.id as id, user.firstName as fullName) FROM User user";
```

Then the return value will form a map structure which is a good format to easily serialize as JSON. You're map (and json) will look like this:

```
{
"id" : "<id value>",

"fullname" : "<firstname value>"
}
```

Comment: Please add more details to your post.  Link only answers are discouraged because they will not be useful if the link provided ever changes.